# Where do I get the correct pdb for msxml6.dll (Symbol Server)

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, pdb-files, msxml6, symbol-server

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to debug a crash in an app and the call stack shows msxml6.dll.

I am running on Windows 7 64 bit.  The app is a 64 bit app.

I set up MS symbol server but it appears my msxml6.dll is not the same/doesn;t match the pdb I get from symbol server.

This is the output I get from running [ChkMatch](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html) on msxml6.dll and the pdb from the symbol server.

```
Executable: C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll
Debug info file: C:\Development\SymbolServer\msxml6.pdb\959E73C66A974E269B0603DA498D5F392\msxml6.pdb

Executable:
TimeDateStamp: 5332e37e
Debug info: 2 ( CodeView )
TimeStamp: 5332de40  Characteristics: 0  MajorVer: 0  MinorVer: 0
Size: 35  RVA: 0010bcec  FileOffset: 0010b0ec
CodeView format: RSDS
Signature: {b6fd5008-d95b-49c5-9228-b26ab92d9e80}  Age: 2
PdbFile: msxml6.pdb
Debug info: 10 ( Unknown )
TimeStamp: 5332de40  Characteristics: 0  MajorVer: 565  MinorVer: 6526
Size: 4  RVA: 0010bce8  FileOffset: 0010b0e8

Debug information file:
Format: PDB 7.00
Signature: {959e73c6-6a97-4e26-9b06-03da498d5f39}  Age: 4

Result: Unmatched (reason: Signature mismatch)
```

Here is the top of the stack in the debugger:

> ```
>  msxml6.dll!assign(IUnknown * * ppref=0x0000000002df12e0, void *
>  pref=0x0000000001bd4180) Line 39 C++
>
>  msxml6.dll!NodeIteratorState::getNext(EnumVariant *
>  pEnum=0x000000000042d600) Line 133   C++
>
>  msxml6.dll!DOMNodeList::nextNode(IXMLDOMNode * *
>  ppNode=0x0000000000000000) Line 3064 C++
> ```

**So my question is - how do I get the correct pdb?**
The stack info is pretty useless without the correct pdb.

[image]

**EDIT**
I downloaded symbols from here:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/download-symbols
and still no luck getting a pdb that matches what is on my machine.

Comment: which version is your msxml6.dll? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: is your app 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: ok, go to system32 folder and look at file properties to see which version you have.

Comment: I want to see if I have the same version so that I can get the PDB

Comment: @magicandre1981  - see question - I edited with version info

Comment: I have a Hotfix version .23403, so I get different PDBs. I have the [convenience roll-up](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3125574) installed and so I have this different version.maybe MS removed this older symbol file. try the update and look if you can get the PDB for the new version now

Comment: Thanks  - I will look into that.  Clients are seeing this problem at their site - so I don't want to lose the current version.  I also see issues with newer msxml6 being reported.  It seems odd that MS would drop the pdb - I thought one of the points of the symbol servers was to provide a pdb for any released version...

Comment: last months MS had perf issues with the symbol server. so maybe they need to cleanup it a bit to make faster

Comment: It happens, the last Win10 update changed it.  More noticeable for kernelbase.dll, everybody uses that one.  Timestamp on the file is March 28th, it installed on my machine a few days ago.  Somebody needs to wake somebody else up to update the MSDL server.  Could be you, call Microsoft Support.

Comment: btw, apply the convenience roll-up to the client, it includes so many fixes, maybe the XML issue is also gone

Comment: Why in the world is there a vote to close this?   Whoever voted to close- please let me know why so i can address the issue.

Comment: again, apply the fix to the client where you see the issue and look if it is already fixed. the MSI symbol package is only valid for the RTM, but any update for a files, makes the PDBs useless.

Comment: have you applied the rollup to the client? Do you still see crashes? if yes, do you get the correct PDB now?

Comment: I have not, Yes and no.  It's a bug elsewhere in code - just happens to exhibit in msxml due to memory corruption.